# Is there an advantage to having individual endpoints over a single endpoint with a path variable?

Tags: java, performance, rest, spring-boot, endpoint

If for example, I have multiple types of electronic devices requesting large files is there any advantage (apart from readability and neatness) of having individual endpoints (or controllers) per device type, like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/device/tablet", method = GET)
    public List<Object> getTabletFile(@RequestBody Object body){
 // code here
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/device/laptop", method = GET)
    public List<Object> getLaptopFile(@RequestBody Object body){
 // code here
}
```

As opposed to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/device/{type}", method = GET)
public List<Object> getFiles(@PathVariable("type") String type, @RequestBody Object body){
 // code here
}
```

I'm wondering in terms of performance, if there is expected to be a high load on the system?

Comment: In your case, first option doesn't really make much sense, because if you wanted to add another type, you would have to create another end point and so on. As for performance, there shouldn't be much difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Don't worry about it.

The overhead of accepting and parsing a new HTTP request is *way* higher than the overhead of extracting one path variable from the URI.

The Spring MVC dispatch routines are heavily optimized; I would expect the overhead of parsing a path variable to be on the order of nanoseconds.

Of course it also depends on what you do with the `type` argument inside the controller. If you just use it in a `switch` statement then it should be fast, and if you do some more lookups/logging/case-insensitive matching/etc. then the overhead will be higher.

Comment: It will be used as part of a file path on the server, a subfolder name.

Comment: Right, so it would be prudent to concentrate more on caching of those files, since the overhead of URL parsing is nothing compared to file I/O.

Comment: Yes, absolutely! That's the next phase :-)